# pruneRoots function returning undefined in the below tree algorithm when removing a node. Unable to make it work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, tree

I am working on Atlassian's plantyourcode challenge. I am on level 4.1. I am a newbie. I am aware of trees, in that, with respect to this problem, when sending nodes of the trees as arguments in a recursive function, they are received by variables and not referenced to the original tree.

I am constantly getting undefined in the final return value after recursion. I am not able to resolve that. The original tree has to be edited, in this case, pruned.

I am stuck on this challenge for days. I have tried methods I read, watched all videos on this and I am at the verge of dropping this challenge at this level. I have only 2 more levels after this, and I want to enter them equipped. I need to know the why behind the right answer and where I am going wrong in my code.

This is how I have been learning, taking part in challenges and solving problems. For me this learning is important. I take this seriously. I hope to get an answer to strengthen my understanding.

Can you please help me with it?

Thank you.

The Q:

Write a function that will return your new root system after you've pruned all unhealthy nodes that don’t have healthy nodes below it.

The Hints provided there:

- We have a root structure in the form of a binary tree where a value of 0 is unhealthy and 1 is healthy. A null value indicates that the node position is empty. A subtree of a node n is n, plus every node that is a descendant of n.

Definition for a binary tree node:

- @param {integer} data - 0 or 1
- @param {Node} left - subtree or null for no left branch
- @param {Node} right - subtree or null for no right branch

> ```
>    function Node(data, left, right) {
>        this.data = data === undefined ? 0 : data;
>       this.left = left === undefined ? null : left;
>       this.right = right === undefined ? null : right;
>  }
> ```

- Complete the following that determines which nodes to prune in order to prune all unhealthy nodes that don't have healthy nodes as children and return the result. Set pruned nodes to null.
- @param {Node} root - binary tree data representing the root system of the plant
- @return {Node} - binary tree data representing the pruned root system of the plant

My code:

```
    function pruneRoots(root) {
        
        
        const removeNode = function(node) {
            
            
          if (node === null) {
            return null;
          }
          if (node.data === 0) {
     
            if(node.left && node.right){
                  if(node.left.data === 0 && node.right.data === 0)
                  {
                          return null;
                  }       
            }
    

            if(node.right && node.right !== null){
            node.right = removeNode(node.right);
            
            }
            if(node.left && node.left !== null){
            node.left = removeNode(node.left);
    
            }
            
          } else if(node.data === 1){
    
    
  
            if(node.right && node.right !== null){
            node.right = removeNode(node.right);
      
            }
            if(node.left && node.left != null){
            node.left = removeNode(node.left);     
           }} 
            return node 
           }
    
            var a = removeNode(root);
        
            console.log(a); //or return a
          }
    
    
 //function call, the root is structured as shown in the argument passed. 

  
    
    pruneRoots({
        "data": 1,
        "left": null,
        "right": {
            "data": 0,
            "left": {
                "data": 0,
                "left": null,
                "right": null
            },
            "right": {
                "data": 0,
                "left": null,
                "right": null
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The indentation of your code could be improved... Also the bullet list you created, is just splitting sentences that belong together. This is hard to read.

Comment: Hi, I have edited them. It is now more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments in your code reveal some misunderstandings.

For instance, the following comment is not describing what the next line of code is doing:

```
// node has no children 
if (node.left && node.right){
```

The above `if` condition is actually testing whether `node` has two children! `node.left` is a "truthy" value when it is an object (i.e. a node), and "falsy" when it is `null`. So you are testing whether both `node.left` and `node.right` are not `null` (as that is the only possible "falsy" value they could have in this context).

The following comment is not always true: it could be that the node only has a right child, but not a left child -- one `if` condition could be true, while the other isn't.

```
// node has two children 
if(node.right && node.right !== null) {
```

Another thing you can improve:

```
console.log(a) //since its on my code editor
//otherwise return a, for the main challenge page
```

You should always `return` here. It is fine to do `console.log` for debugging purposes, but make sure to `return` it as well, also when testing.

### Logic

There is a logical error in your algorithm:

```
if (node.left && node.right){
    if(node.left.data === 0 && node.right.data === 0) {
        return null
    }       
}
```

This is not right, as `node.left.left` could still have a value 1 (i.e. be healthy), so it would be wrong to return `null` then. The key insight here is that you should *first* do the recursive calls on `node.left` and on `node.right` and *then* check whether these nodes were pruned as a result. If so, only then you can decide to also prune the current `node` (and return `null`).

### Recursion

You made a nested function to perform the recursion with. But it really offers no advantage over using the main `pruneRoots` function recursively: it takes the same type of argument and returns the same type. You might as well use `pruneRoots` recursively.

### Corrected

So here is a corrected version:

```js
function pruneRoots(root) {
    if (root === null) {
        return null;
    }
    // First perform the recursive pruning
    root.left = pruneRoots(root.left);
    root.right = pruneRoots(root.right);
    // Now we can be sure that if a child still exists, 
    // there must be a healthy node in its subtree 
    if (root.data === 0 && !root.left && !root.right) { // Not healthy and no children
        return null;
    }
    // In all other cases, don't prune the node
    return root;
}

let result = pruneRoots({
    "data": 1,
    "left": null,
    "right": {
        "data": 0,
        "left": {
            "data": 0,
            "left": null,
            "right": null
        },
        "right": {
            "data": 0,
            "left": null,
            "right": null
        }
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks! the logic part of your answer made a difference in my understanding. I understood the problem as any node with data as 0 and having left and right whose data as 0 could be deleted right away with no worries of node.left.left having 1 or a healthy root. That is why I went on and on and messed it up.

I also did not think of recursing the roots before performing any action on them. I can distinctly see the left and right branches in your code and then checking and removing nodes from the bottom most all the way up to the top. I will also incorporate other points in future! thank you!